# in java, why abstract class Number can be instantiated?

Tags: java

As far as I know, Number is an abstract class in Java, but why it can be instantiated just like codes below?

```
Vector vec = new Vector(4);

vec.add(4);
vec.add(3);
vec.add(2);
vec.add(1);
vec.add(3.55);

Number[] anArray = new Number[vec.size()];
anArray = (Number[]) vec.toArray(anArray);
```

Comment: where do you initialize `Number` ?

Comment: Where is it instantiated in this code? Note an Array is quite a different thing.

Comment: Also, don't use `Vector`, and learn about generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not instantiating a `Number`.  You're instantiating a `Number[]`.  These are two *completely* different objects.

You can generally expect to be able to instantiate an array of any type, even types that you can't *directly* instantiate yourself.  You can populate these arrays through type inheritance and the **is-a** relationship.

For example, with the above, you could put any `Number` in there you wanted - 1, 2.0, 1.4f, and so forth.